# SwiperOptions does not work in Angular app

Tags: angular, customization, swiper.js

I'm a newbie with angular and I want to use swiper 10 for a carrousel (for angular 16).

I want to customize my carrousel with `swiperOptions` but anything happened.

In my app.component.ts, I register Swiper :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    register();
  }
}
```

My carrousel :

```
<swiper-container [config]="config">
     <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>
     <swiper-slide>Slide 2</swiper-slide>
     <swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
     <swiper-slide>Slide 4</swiper-slide>
</swiper-container>
```

and my carrousel-component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SwiperOptions } from 'swiper/types';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-project',
  templateUrl: './carrousel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./carrousel.component.scss'],
})
export class CarrouselComponent {

  public config: SwiperOptions = {
    navigation: true,
    slidesPerView: 2,
};
}
```

I even tried what explained here [text](https://swiperjs.com/element#installation) with script tag but still nothing work...

Is there something I forgot ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: are you  also facing any error in console ?

Comment: Any error… if I set up properties directly in my swiper-container tag it works but when use swiperOptions anything happened. Any error, any message...

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the configurations as `attributes` on the swiper-container it works fine, kindly make this change.

```
<swiper-container [slidesPerView]="2" [navigation]="true">
     <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>
     <swiper-slide>Slide 2</swiper-slide>
     <swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
     <swiper-slide>Slide 4</swiper-slide>
</swiper-container>
```

---

#### References

1. [Reference Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/swiper-angular-example)